# How to make second function argument optional depending on first

Tags: typescript

I want to make type for Vue emit function. So it should be possible to describe all events in one place. But some events does not include payload.

I want API like this or something similar:

```js
const emit = getEmit<{input: string, toggle: never}>()

emit("input", "some text")
emit("toggle")
```

I tried to achieve this using mapped type and then creating union from it.

```js
type Emit<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends never?
    (event: K) => void:
    (event: K, payload: T[K]) => void
}

export const getEmit = <T>(): Emit<T>[keyof T] => {
  const instance = getCurrentInstance()

  return instance?.emit ?? () => {}
}
```

emit type looks like normal but it doesn't work.

```js
const Status = "initial" | "final"

const emit = getEmit<{toggle: never, change: Status}>()

// event type:
// ((event: "toggle") => void) | ((event: "change", payload: "initial") => void) | ((event: "change", payload: "final") => void)

emit("toggle") // Expected 2 arguments, but got 1
emit("change", "initial") // Arguments of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
```

Is there a way to make what I want? Thank you.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488717/declaring-dependent-argument-types-for-optional-arguments-with-conditional-types/64796265#64796265

Comment: I believe this article should help you https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Usi mentioned you can use tuple parameter type for this.
In my case it looks like this:

```js
export const getEmit = <T>(): <K extends keyof T>(event: K, ...args: T[K] extends never? []: [payload: T[K]]) => void => {
  const instance = getCurrentInstance()

  return instance?.emit ?? () => {}
}
```